# Can I do publish my paper without APC?

Tags: publications, physics, open-access

Now a days,I have no money to pay for Article Processing charge (APC) since I have no money support foundation.I want to publish my paper without paying any amount of money in an international journal .For this, I need the names of some international, prestigious physical journals in which I can easily publish my paper without APC in open access .I will be grateful if anyone can help me in this case.
Many many thanks.

Comment: Are all journals in your discipline open access?  In my disciplines, many journals are free to publish unless you exceed the page limit, in which case that will attract page charges.

Comment: Closing this for being a [shopping question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657). What you can ask about here is *how* to find such a journal, but in physics, this should really not be a major hurdle – I know of only two relevant pay-to-publish journals. Things become a bit different if you require open access, but then you should first ask yourself whether you really require this in a field where supporting preprint publication is the norm. So, if you wish to ask about the *how,* please specify what your real constraints and difficulties are.

Comment: https://scipost.org/

Comment: @Wrzlprmft There are more than two gold open access journals in physics now:  https://journals.aps.org/authors/apcs#pricing https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/2022-iop-publishing-apc-prices/

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can! There are two ways:

- Publish in a subscription journal. Most of the biggest journals in physics are still primarily subscription. For example, the Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics [says](https://iopscience.iop.org/journal/1475-7516/page/publication-charges):

> Subscription publication is free of charge.

- If you can't publish in a subscription journal, you can request a waiver. Example from [MDPI](https://www.mdpi.com/apc):

> For journals in fields with low levels of funding, where authors typically do not have funds available, APCs are typically waived and cross-subsidized from fields for which more APC funding is available. For authors from low- and middle-income countries, waivers or discounts may be granted on a case-by-case basis. Applications submitted before article submission are assessed by the Managing Editor based on the quality of the research article and the authors’ ability to pay.